# Combining Angular and Twig

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig

I've already done:

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');
```

So that there is no conflict with the `{{` of Twig variables.

But when it comes to combining the two I'm not sure what to do. Like this:

```
<div class="tile {{ getRoleColour({[{ user.role }]}) }}">
```

Which obviously doesn't work.

`user.role` is the angular var, `getRoleColour()` is my twig extension.

Any ideas?

Comment: Twig is renderd server-side, you can't interact with it's functionality through angular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

@yoshi is right: Twig is renderd server-side, you can't interact with it's functionality through angular expressions.

The best way to be that is to not use inline server-side code like  but to use a service to load all your data and inject your service in your controller and work on its value as javascript value.